# refreshing a php page on submit

Tags: php, form-submit, onsubmit

I have a php page, which includes a form. I am able to correctly edit the information on the form through MYSQL queries. I am able to edit and change the values in mysql database.
However when I press submit it shows me the old value and I have to do a manual refresh in order to get the new value. 
I am using this code in order to be able to have the automatic refresh on SUBMIT.

```
<?php
    if((isset($_GET['refresh']))) {
    ?>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

and my form : `<form class="fill-up" action="" method=post>`

I am not sure why this doesnt work. can someone provide help. I could find anything useful in other Question here that are like this.

Comment: Why not put your `UPDATE ...` query before your `SELECT ...` query, so that it updates the form data first, then selects it / populates the form, so that you don't have to refresh again to get the updated data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending the form data to the same page the form is on with action="", send it to another php page/script and then redirect back to the form page with

```
<?php

header("Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/form-page.php");

?>
```

At the end of your php script that processes the form data.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit submit your variables are POSTed (or GETed), there is no magic method for keeping them. We would need to see the entire code to determine why you are having this problem. However doing what you are trying to with that code won't accomplish anything but loosing your changed (actually it won't do anything at all)